# Which PE header fields are used by windows loader?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I'm trying to understand PE header files produced by an executable compressor.

I've been told all the header fields that Windows uses in this case are intact. All other, on the other hand, contain complete garbage from the PE header perspective. I'm trying to understand which ones are relevant ones.

Let's say I got this `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`:

[image]

And this `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`:

[image]

When I open my executable on the debugger, it immediately stops at this address:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
0040005C    53              PUSH EBX
```

So, how does the debugger knows 0x0040005C is the location it needs to start debugging at? What'd be the formula to calculate this "entry point" address?

I guess the main question here is, which PE header files are relevant from the windows perspective loader and which ones will be used for some other purposes by  these type of packers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` only `e_magic` (for check) and `e_lfanew`(offset to `IMAGE_NT_HEADERSXX` (32 or 64) ) used. you need look for `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` fields. entry point calc very easy

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER ImageBase;
if (ImageBase->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 pinth32;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 pinth64;

    };
    pv = RtlOffsetToPointer(ImageBase, ImageBase->e_lfanew);
    DWORD AddressOfEntryPoint = 0;
    switch (pinth32->OptionalHeader.Magic)
    {
    case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC:
        AddressOfEntryPoint = pinth32->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        break;
    case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC:
        AddressOfEntryPoint = pinth64->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        break;
    }
    PVOID EntryPoint = AddressOfEntryPoint ? RtlOffsetToPointer(ImageBase, AddressOfEntryPoint) : 0;
}
```

so look to `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint`

> When I open my executable on the debugger, it immediately stops at
>   this address:

bad debugger :) good must stop at `LdrInitializeThunk`

Comment: @ look for `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint` not for `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`

Comment: `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.SizeOfOptionalHeader` - the size of the optional header, in bytes. it can be `!= sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)` - because exist 32 and 64 bit version of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`, also number of the `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY` in the end of IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER can be different. look for example macro `IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION`

Comment: it cannot be 0x8 - you mistake

Comment: "compressed PE header" - i don't know what you mean. take good peviewer and llook

Comment: now view. `e_lfanew==4` as result `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32` overrides `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` - AddressOfEntryPoint at 0x2c offset is 0x5c. but some data (like SizeOfOptionalHeader) is incorrect. but it primary used to got first `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` but here `NumberOfSections == 0`. may be this PE and loaded - but ugly hack

Comment: this exe working ? what sence at all speak about this concrete encrypted image ?